# Is it possible to get an address from lat and lng in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, google-maps

I have lat and lng in a table.

How can I get address from lat and lng ? I tried this :

```
using Artem.Google.Net;

SqlConnection con = 
    new SqlConnection("Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=sa;Password=");
con.Open();
var com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Trucks WHERE plate=@id", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", truckPlate.Trim());
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    labelLat.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
    labelLat.DataBind();

    labelLng.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
    labelLng.DataBind();

    double lat = Convert.ToDouble(labelLat.Text);
    double lng = Convert.ToDouble(labelLng.Text);

    GeoRequest request = new GeoRequest(lat, lng);
    GeoResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    string address = response.Results[0].FormattedAddress;

    lblAddress.Text = address.ToString();
}
else
{
    labelNote.Text="Truck is offline";
}
```

Error :

```
      System.ArgumentException: Requested 'bus_station' value is not found
```

at this line

```
    GeoResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

I dont have "bus_station" in SQL or in Aspx code.What is this ?

Comment: I think the question should be "Is it possible to get address(es) from latitude/longitude values using Google Maps API".  From there, it would be easy enough to figure out what to do in c# (or any other language).

Comment: The magic word is [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) (The process of translating a location on the map into a human-readable address is known as reverse geocoding)